# what to do to get access to client's PayPal a/c as only the developer

Tags: paypal

If i am developer, and my client wants accept payments like express checkout (only one button)... well what to do to get access to client's PayPal a/c as only the developer?

Comment: Ask your client to give you permission to access his PayPal account. He can authorize that, if he wants to.

Comment: going live for express checkout, after success sandbox tests, needs business account? if not how get api keys in all cases?

Comment: paypal offers subuser to an account creation?

Comment: if requires biz a/c for express checkout like  http://www.paphoscarhire.mobi/book-droushia/index3.php   then what to do to convert to biz a/c?

Comment: I can get access - no problem - so I will use normal method... well how get real keys? needed biz a/c?

Comment: There are a lot of questions about using PayPal API on SO. It is NOT an easy thing to work with, I now realize. I noticed your earlier question, from a few weeks ago. The only thing I can suggest is that you tag this question with [tag:paypal] so it is more likely to be noticed by someone who can help you. Someone from PayPal, it is in his user name, provides support on SO for questions that are tagged with that "brand" tag.

Comment: can you answer ONLY this... To use express checkout like url in one comment above(sandbox example) NEEDED BIZ PAYPAL account?

Comment: No. Tag the question like I suggested, and maybe someone else can help you. I am sorry, I don't know the answer.